# xterm -pob in MATE 1.16

Tags: xterm, mate-desktop

`xterm -pob` does not raise the window when it receives <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> (MATate 1.16, RHEL7).  This used to work fine in Gnome2, RHEL6.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a known issue (with the window managers) for which a recent workaround was made ([patch #352](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_352)):

> improve portability of iconify/deiconify feature by taking into account some window managers which manipulate the EWMH **`_NET_WM_STATE`** property, adding/removing **`_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN`** rather than actually minimizing the window (prompted by discussion with Jörg Breitbart).

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the latest xterm from that link, and still same behavior.   Works fine on same machine with mwm, so I think it's a MATE issue.  (I like the multiple desktops, which mwm lacks.)

Comment: I see (mis-recalled the calls used).  This particular one uses `XRaiseWindow`.  It might be similar case (in the one cited, the window manager doesn't respond to the X events for minimizing/unminimizing the window).